# Images have purple ring

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have images on my page which a liked using `<a href=""><img><\a>`  and when they are being displayed in chrome and firefox they work fine, but on IE they have a purple ring around the images any ideas why the would be the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a border, IE puts borders around images in links, use `a img{border:none}` to remove it.

Comment: this method is not wokring

Comment: @user2108195 no need to repeat yourself, this does work http://jsfiddle.net/mKbS7/2/, unless you can produce this behaviour for me to see I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

for images `border: 0px;outline: 0px;` bye good luck

Comment: this method is not wokring

Comment: well, don´t know how you are trying it, but should work, or put a fiddle where it shows that border, border: 0;outline: 0; obviously for all the images. bye.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the border for the link in IE.
This is best done with `a img { border: none}`